# Why node js project not run on IP address on alibaba cloud

Tags: node.js, amazon-ec2, alibaba-cloud

I have successfully deployed node js project on Alibaba cloud and running on port 2021 and 2020 i have export that port no and also added on ECS on Alibaba cloud instance.

when i run command `pm2 start 0,1` its status is online but when i hit that port no with IP address on browser its not working i google it and spend lots of time but not found any solution this is my first deployment on Alibaba cloud any help thanks in advance.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you please add the output of `netstat -ntpl`. I'm assuming your ECS has a public IP/EIP and you're using it for SSH, correct?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the screenshots provided, the application is kept restarting so it seems like the application is not stable enough to accept the connections.

Try to curl the application on server with port and check if it returns the answers with the following

- curl http://localhost:2000
- curl http://localhost:2021

more on curl request can be found here https://blog.logrocket.com/an-intro-to-curl-the-basics-of-the-transfer-tool/

If there are no answers then try checking the logs by running

```
pm2 logs
```